# Load data in batches from MongoDB when the query field may contain same values

Tags: mongodb

here's the scenario. I'd like to load data in batches.
For example, first find 'student_id' {'gt': 20} limit (10)，then I fetch the last docs returned from the query, let's say student_id 30, then I do the second query  find 'student_id' {'gt': 30} limit (10) until there is no data can be load, then all the student data is fetched.
but if I want to do this for a field with same value, let's say age $gt 15, then how to construct the later queries. If I use combine index in mongo, (age, student_id), then the last element returned from the query 'age' {'gt': 15} limit (10) is student(age:16, student_id:24).
Is there anything like 'age_student_id': {'gt': 16_24} in mongo, so I can continue do the later queries.

Some additional information, I searched about the skip and cursor function in mongo, but this seems will consume large amount of memory since mongo need to sort all the range and remember where the cursor is.
Another solution I'm currently using is use 2 combined condtions, it's like {$or: [{'age': {$gt: 16}}, {'age': {'$eq': 16}, {'student_id': {'gt': 24}}}]} to skip previous queried data. but when the query becomes more complicate, maybe 3 condtions or 4 conditions, this solution is difficult to extend

What I'm trying is to load data in batches, and this functionality can separate large amount data loading into little pieces.